# Automatically update MPD database upon external storage insertion

Tags: upgrade, usb-drive, udev, database, music

I have an Alix board in my living room running Voyage MPD edition and acting as jukebox.

In order to play "guest" music, I would like that MPD automatically updates its database with the content of the USB sticks one could connect to the box.
Is there a straightforward way to do it (via udev or MPD) ?

Thanks

Comment: If you already know what udev and mpd are, it would be a nice little exercise for you to write a script that would do it. The tricky part is to look for how to run a command after external drive insertion (search engines may help you...)